# Cannot set Background Image of Grid Windows Store App through XAML

Tags: windows, xaml, store

I am trying to change the background image of my my App but it only accepts default Four images that are placed in Assets folder. ie Logo.png, widelogo.png etc. OR it accepts an PNG with same name as these files in Assets folder.

But I want to attach a BG Image with different name i.e Background.png. I am trying this XAML but it shows nothing:

```
<Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="Pics/bg.png"/>
</Grid.Background>
```

I am new. Plz Guide me

Comment: is your Pics folder added to the project?

Comment: Yes It is. "Pics" is the folder name inside the project folder.

Comment: I dont see any problem with the code. Just check the image name and path.

Comment: What do you have the build action set to for your bg.png file properties?